# How to Add icon on the matched Google Places Reviews (right side) shown in Google Search Results

Tags: jquery, google-chrome-extension

The extension that i am developing is adding icon next to the google search links, using jquery. But the problem is i am not able to add the same icon when google places reviews sections appears when you click on any search result that has plus.google.com on it.

Here's the screen shot of what i am referring to: (note the tick icons)
[image]

So far i have successfully managed to show icon next to the searcg result link by matching a pattern but i have no clue how to put icon next to the big title shown on the right side. Because it loads on click, so do i have to run my matching script whenever user clicks?

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Tow possible ways to do this:

- Use **DOMNodeInserted** mutation event to determine if new elements subtree added to the page. It should be relatively lightweight event handler because it may be called very often on some pages. Also Please note that this even may never fire for element you are looking for but for its parent. Examine the inserted element or its children for specif place and add your icon.
- Use timer. Find specific element using jQuery selector in timer handler.

Second way is preferred if you plan to implement Firefox compatible script and use it in Firefox addon later. Mutation events will bring review warning for addons. However from my experience DOMNodeInserted event listener works much better (faster and easier to support)